# Mouse and KeyBoards Not Working after Power Failure

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I was working with a small form desktop computer when a transformer exploded on the city power grid causing a power failure and flickering lights in the office. When I turned the computer back on, the USB mouse and keyboard no longer light up when plugged in (or work), but the OS loads just fine.

I thought maybe the USB ports were ruined, but a usb thumb drive with a light on it lights up. How can I troubleshoot the mouse and keyboard problem? There is not response from the keyboard even before boot at the bios prompt.

EDIT: The mouse and keyboard work fine on other computers.

Comment: goto device manager and reinstall them, it will be ok, maybe !

Comment: @Sam  potential problem, I can't control anything because the input devices aren't working.

Comment: maybe it's related to the power stuff , test with the other keyboard or mouse and let me know any changes...

Comment: Install PCI usb ports and check

Comment: @JMC Does your desktop have PS2 ports ?

Comment: @pun - PS2 ports turned out to be the solution for now. I believe the power failure destroyed the USB ports because certain device lights flicker for a second then go out when I plug them in.

Comment: In your question, you say USB thumb drives light up (you don't indicate whether you've tested that they work).  In a comment, you say that certain devices flicker and then go out.  If any device works in the port, it means the port, itself, isn't damaged.  The sudden power loss could have caused corruption on your hard drive, and the problem could be just corrupted drivers.  It wouldn't hurt to run chkdsk and sfc /scannow to check for and clean up possible corruption.  Since you got it working with PS2, also check Device Manager per Sam's comment.